# While loop not breaking out even if condition is false

Tags: javascript, while-loop

A `Javascript` newbie here.

I was trying to make this simple program where the webpage will show the brute-force of any word you enter, every iteration. For now, I have limited it to `console.log()`. The code goes on something like this -

```
document.getElementById("intro").onclick = function(){
    alphabets = "abcdefghijklmnoqrstuvwxyz";
    text = alphabets[0];
    word = "foobar";
    i=0;
    j=0;
    for(i=0; i<word.length; i++){
        while(text.charAt(text.length - 1)!=word[i]){
            j++;
            text = text.substring(0, text.length - 1);
            text+=alphabets[j];
            //document.getElementById("word") = text;
        }
        console.log("found a matching letter!");
        j=0;
    }
}
```

***Note:-*** *if you've gone through the `while` loop, just ignore the fact that once it finds a matching word for the first character, it will not got to the next one as the length( of `text`) will end up being constant*

Whenever this code is executed, it just goes into a state of an infinite while loop and makes the page completely unresponsive. I tried `console.log(text)` and it gives an output something like this -

[image]

Notice, how it doesn't `console.log()` the character `p`. So, I would expect it to exit the while loop that time and print the code outside the `while` loop(`console.log("found a matching letter!");` and `j=0;`). But, in the picture above, as you can see, it doesn't get printed out. I then `console.log(j)` only to find it being printed continuously in an infinite loop while incrementing itself.

I honestly don't know what is happening or I'm missing something very obvious. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You could do this with a for loop and create a statement around the true/false value and do a `break;` around that. That'll break you out of the loop.

Comment: where is `console.log(text)` in the code?

Comment: *it doesn't console.log() the character p* -- "p" is not in the alphabets string.

Comment: `text.substring(0, text.length - 1);`   Is this working as intended?  `substring` returns up to but not including the end-index value so `- 1` doesn't seem correct.

Comment: perhaps `while( j < alphabets.length)` instead and remove `text` variable altogether. As a general principle I think Iterating over a string ( or array) while changing its length is just asking for trouble.